# I can't see Release Build in Visual studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net

I have a website (target framework 2.0) , I install VS 2010 Ultimate on Windows 7 Professional, The problem is When I open the website, I'm trying to change the Build configuration from Debug->Release, There no "Release" item option in Solution Configuration drop-down list, which is on the Standard toolbar. even when i right click of solution and select properties, then Configuration Properties, I can see Active(Debug) only.

I need to publish a released copy. (in other word, no html code in aspx files)

Answer (score 5):

Release configuration is not available for Web Sites. You have two options:

- Right click the project and "Publish Site", or
- Get the web deployment add-on at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24509. This will allow you to package your site and get it ready for deployment.

I prefer the second option, it has many benefits, provides more options, and if you do it right, it can help with the deployment process.

Comment: +1 - one of many reasons to use a web application project rather than a web site.

Comment: I agree with John. Web Application is the way to go :)

Comment: You mean, we can't set release mode for ASP.NET website rite?